# "Clipped" Bottom of Circular div When min-height Set

Tags: html, css, chromium

I have this loader (rendered HTML):

```html
<div class="shuffle-loader">
    <span class="shuffle-loader__dot">
      ::after
    </span>
    <span class="shuffle-loader__dot">
      ::after
    </span>
    <span class="shuffle-loader__dot">
      ::after
    </span>
    <span class="shuffle-loader__dot">
      ::after
    </span>
</div>
```

```css
/* important css snipet: */
.shuffle-loader {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
}
.shuffle-loader__dot::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
  animation: shuffle 2.4s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: " ";
}
.shuffle-loader__dot {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
@keyframes shuffle {
  0%,
  95%,
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  /* etc. */
}
/* Plus some .shuffle-loader__dot:nth-child(1)::after selectors for varied colors, etc. See codepen. */
```

[image: Animation]

Works well. **However, it seems a certain combination of CSS properties on a wrapping element causes part of the bottom-right circle to get "clipped"**:

[image: Clipped]

```css
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

If I remove any of these properties from `.wrapper`, the loader renders just fine (except, of course, that it's not where I want it on the page).

Here's a [codepen reproduction](https://codepen.io/connorjameslow/pen/OJmoZoZ) of the issue.

This seems to only happen on Chromium browsers. **What's going here? Is it just an engine bug?**

---

**Update 08/06/2021**: the visual effect is only present when the animation is active (i.e. commenting out the animation "fixes" it); I'm guessing it's a chromium rendering bug related to animations.

Comment: I don't see that issue using Chrome on Ubuntu at your codepen link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround based on [this Chromium bug discussion](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157218#c16): adding a `rotate(0deg)` transformation on the `0%` step of the animation.

```css
@keyframes shuffle {
    0%, 95%, 100% {
        transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg);
    }
  /* etc. */
```

I don't really understand how, but it works.