# Explain how adding rotate(0deg) fixed a my rendering bug

Tags: html, css, chromium

[Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68659259), I was experiencing a visual bug on an animated element:

[image: Animation]

Briefly, the final (bottom right) of four circles had a couple of flattened faces:

[image: Clipped]

I found a workaround: add `rotate(0deg)` to one of the animation keyframes.

```css
@keyframes shuffle {
    0%, 95%, 100% {
        transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg); /* fixed! */
    }
    20%, 25% {
        transform: translate(2.5rem, 0);
    }
    /* etc. */
}
```

[image: Fixed version]

**Why does this work?** I got the idea from [this chromium bug discussion](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157218#c16), but I don't really understand it (something about promoting it to its own layer/context).